# Share Intel vGPU to Hyper-V client machines

Tags: windows, hyper-v

[This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/mym1ab/has_anyone_had_any_success_with_intel_gvtg/) although not updated shows how to set up a vGPU to be used by client virtual machines in a KVM environment.

So my Linux experiment actually worked and the Windows Guest Machine did manage to have a vGPU (via GVT-g) while the physical machine only having a single GPU.

I just don't know yet how to translate the process to Hyper-V to which you will create a vGPU that you will physically assign to a virtual machine.

How can that be done in a Windows 10 environment?

Comment: Does Hyper-V support passing through a video adapter at all

Comment: @TomYan yeah from what I have tested in a physical GPU before I was able to pass through Sapphire GPU without error 403

Comment: You can either use RemoteFX (security risk!) or DDA, for more information on both and how to implement them, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/plan-for-gpu-acceleration-in-windows-server

Comment: @Silbee - RemoteFX was removed back in April, and all supported versions of Windows 10 and most definitely not a realistic solution to the author’s problem